# MikTeX x86 vs MikTeX x86_64

Tags: miktex

I've found that MikTeX now have [both x86 and x86_64 version](http://miktex.org/download).

What's the difference between them? Are there are some limitations in the x86_64? Or they are completely interchangeably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MiKTeX 64-bit distribution is considered experimental, i.e., not ready for production use, according to the developer. He wrote this on his blog [Mai 11, 2011](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/05/11/LuaTeX-0700.aspx), and did not state otherwise yet. In his [newest blog post](http://blog.miktex.org/post/2011/09/15/MiKTeX-on-Windows-8.aspx) he said that he's testing MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit with Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

There are no significant performance differences between the x86/64 versions of MiKTeX.
But between MiKTeX and TeX Live, particularly with including, scaling and other operations on pdf pages.

<strike>And there is no biber in MiKTeX 64.</strike><sup>1</sup>

1. As of summer 2015, 64-bit MikTeX also includes Biber in its repositories.

Comment: As of now, Biber is available also for 64-bit MikTeX.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same but you have to know if you system is 32 or 64 bit. This is the difference.

Comment: If you have a 64bit system, you can use either of them. Has anybody got an idea whether there are compatability issues or if the 64bit version is significantly faster?