# How can I find out whether I have 32bit or 64bit of MiKTeX installed?

Tags: miktex

I am trying to debug a problem with biber not being available. I know it's not in 64bit. So I need to find out what the machine's installation of MiKTeX has.

Comment: Well, great! I just found out that it's 64bit. It seems ProTeXT in all it's wisdom installs 64bit version of MiKTeX!!! That's the last time I'm using that

Comment: One option: if the miktex path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9` then it's 32-bit and if its `C:\Program Files\miktex 2.9` then it's 64-bit miktex. Related [How can one install biber on miktex 64-bit?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154708/15717) and [MikTeX x86 vs MikTeX x86_64](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89822/15717)

Comment: Thanks, you should make this into an answer. It is indeed true, that paths are different and reflect the architecture type.

Comment: Please self answer (as its acceptable) since you already found the answer first and add some of my details if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few notes here:

1. If the miktex path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9` then it's 32-bit and if its `C:\Program Files\miktex 2.9` then it's 64-bit miktex
2. [ProTeXt](https://www.tug.org/protext/), at present, installs 64bit version of MikTeX. (The version of MiKTeX being installed is visible during the setup procedure). So I suggest not using it if you need specific version of MiKTeX. Instead go directly to http://www.miktex.org/