# Problem after transition BibTex to [BibLaTex,Biber]

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I've been using TexMaker and MikTex under Windows10 for 3-4 months and I managed to convert the short .odt thesis I wanted to submit into a .tex file. For the bibliography, I used Jabref and BibTex.

Now I've considered making the transition to BibLaTex with Biber for a new work requiring the use of Unicode for the bibliography.

However I get an issue which doesn't seem related to the use of Unicode since it persists even with a minimal code.
My minimal .tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblioessai.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{Bau2003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My .bib file is the following:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{Bau2003,
title     = {Dictionnaire persan-français, français-persan ordre latin},
publisher = {La Maison du dictionnaire},
year      = {2003},
author    = {Bau, Pierre and Lazard, Gilbert},
address   = {Paris},
isbn      = {2-85608-177-0},
pages     = {1 vol. (XXV-533 p.)},
url       = {http://www.sudoc.fr/075605902},
}
```

I've configured TexMaker with "biber %" under the Bib(La)Tex field and tried to run multiple times PdfLaTex and Bib(La)Tex alternatively, but it always gives me the following error message:

> Process started
>
> lib.pm did not return a true value at -e line 165.
>
> Process exited with error(s)

The .pdf file I get is a one page document containing only "[Bau2003]" on the top; the bibliography doesn't appear. (I feel it may be an unrelated issue but after searching for the whole afternoon I'm a bit confused...)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show us the `.blg` file? Even though the `pages` field is malformed as noted by Bernard below, that should not leas to such an error? Can you update Biber (and then also `biblatex` with it) using MikTeX's Updater (in both Admin *and* User mode, you might have to run the Updaters twice)? Can you run `biber --version` on the command line? If so, what is the output?

Comment: @moewe oooooh you're right!! no .blg file has appeared! I'll search how to update Biber!

Comment: Thank you sooo much!!! I uninstalled then reinstalled BibLaTex through MikTex Package Manager, and Biber through the file biber.exe in C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/ It works now!

Comment: If that implies that you installed Biber manually and not via the Package Manager, please consider removing the manual install and install Biber using the Package Manager. That way you can be sure that your versions of Biber and `biblatex` match. Make sure to run the Updaters after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small problem with the `pages`fields, which is not relevant (should be `pagetotal`.  Mentioning the number of volumes with the `volumes` field works only with several volumes (you obtain `vols 1`…), so I used the `note`  field.

That said, this code compiles for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Biblioessai.bib}
@Book{Bau2003,
title = {Dictionnaire persan-français, français-persan ordre latin},
publisher = {La Maison du dictionnaire},
year = {2003},
author = {Bau, Pierre and Lazard, Gilbert},
address = {Paris},
isbn = {2-85608-177-0},
pagetotal = {(xxv  + 533 p.)},
note={1 vol.},
url = {http://www.sudoc.fr/075605902},
}
\end{filecontents}}


\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblioessai.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Bau2003}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the information that the book constitutes of one volume is important at all, it could be moved to the `volumes` field. I also would not include the brackets in the `pagetotal` field, that is something that should be left to the style. If `+` is declared a NumChar the automatic page numbering will then even work. (`pagetotal = {xxv + 533}, volumes   = {1},`)

Comment: @moewe: That's what I tried first, but biblatex uses the  plural (`1 vols`)… For  the parentheses, it's traditional in French typography, as far as I know. How does one declare `+` a NumChar? I don't know this procedure…

Comment: Ah yes, I should have seen the s. (Obviously PL thought it wouldn't make sense to have `volumes = {1}`; one could change that of course to detect if singular is needed.) `\DeclareNumChars` seems to be the command to make characters NumChars ... If brackets are traditional in French typography we probably just need `\DeclareFieldFormat{pagetotal}{\mkbibparens{\mkpagetotal[bookpagination]{#1}}}` and can still get rid of the brackets in the `.bib` file (what if you decide it isn't tradition after all, or you want to follow a language with different traditions?)

Comment: @Moewe: Yes, it makes sense. At least, I've often seen it in (French) antique booksellers' catalogues. For the brackets, I can patch specifically for the French language, but it would be better to have as an option, in my opinion.

Comment: I've been found out ^^ yep I'm writing in French! Thank you Bernard for your fast answer, I've tried but it doesn't seem to work for me, the same error message appears; as moewe pointed out above, it may have something to do with Biber

Comment: Did you compile only this code?

Comment: I compiled another code, very similar, then reduced it to a minimal code to show it here, but nothing else. Anyway, thank you, it seems to work now!!! I uninstalled then reinstalled BibLaTex through MikTex Package Manager, and Biber through the file biber.exe in C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/, and suppressed all files outside the .bib and .tex ones before trying to compile again (PdfLaTex - Bib(La)Tex/Biber - PdfLaTex).

Comment: Fine! What's not clear: do you have MiKTeX 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I suppose `volumes = {1}` is as implied as `edition = {1}` if it is not given, so it may as well be left out; but I can see some cases where one might want to explicitly see it. Still, I believe `volumes` is the right place and the format needs to be adapted a bit. Re the brackets around `pagetotal`, I'm not sure what option you would want to see and why you would only change the format for French (works?, I assume) - wouldn't that just lead to inconsistencies? Either wrap all `pagetotal` fields in brackets with the code from above, or not - I wouldn't make that language dependent.

Comment: @Bernard according to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161701/how-can-i-find-out-whether-i-have-32bit-or-64bit-of-miktex-installed, since my path is C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9 , it should be 32 bit...